# Grouping unique column values to get average of each unique value in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, mean

I am trying to take a pandas dataframe and get the average for each unique value in a column from the corresponding values in another column.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
Charge Code Days 
1001-000    132
1001-000    48
1001-000    12
1001-000    22
1001-000    38
1001-000    22
1001-000    36
1001-000    931
1001-000    973
1001-000    53
1001-000    69
1001-000    69
1001-000    973
1001-000    69
1001-000    69
1001-000    69
1001-000    52
1001-000    973
1001-000    87
1001-000    973
1001-000    55
1001-000    55
1001-000    55
1001-000    55
1001-000    220
1002-000    39
1002-000    28
1002-000    16
1003-000    945
1003-000    25
1003-000    41
```

I am using the following line:

```
df_Paid.groupby(level=0)['Charge Code'].mean()
```

to try and get the desired dataframe:

```
Charge Code Days
1001-000   244
1002-000   28
1003-000   337
```

which is the average number of days for each charge code. When I use this line I get the following error:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly.

Comment: Try df_Paid.groupby('Charge Code')['Days'].mean()

Comment: Try `df_Paid.groupby('Charge Code').mean()`.

Comment: it returns the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, maybe -

```
df_Paid['Days'] = df_Paid['Days'].astype(int)
df_Paid.groupby(['Charge Code'])['Days'].mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `df_Paid.groupby('Charge Code')['days'].mean()`
you should be good.
Here is a good reference for the use of groupby() : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html
Look up Hierarchical Indexes there.

Comment: Change the datatype to int64 - df_Paid['Days'] = df_Paid['Days'].astype(int)
OR
```import numpy as np
df_Paid['Days'] = df_Paid['Days'].astype(np.int64)```